# UIPopoverPresentationController should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs

Tags: html, objective-c, ipad, cordova, ios8

The app I developed is mainly built using `phonegap build 3.5.0` is anyone having similar issues with there app crashing constantly.

Main issues
First issue is the HTML select element when the user tap this element serval times repeatedly the application will crash.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSGenericException'`, reason: `'UIPopoverPresentationController (UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7c7b4510)should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'`

Can you please help me, to solve this issue.

Comment: same problem with UIWebView on iPad 8.2 for input. clicking 2-3 times quickly on input cause crash.

Comment: its iOS issue, after updating iOS 7 to 8.3. its working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Please check the below code.may be this help you.

```
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    //if iPad
    else
    {
        // Change Rect to position Popover
        UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
        NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.width/2);
        [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: its iOS issue, after updating iOS 7 to 8.3. its working fine.